# c# mongo 2.0 reduce traffic of FindAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have to get some minor data from each document I have in the database but I still want to reduce traffic to prevent "Table-Scan" (just the term, i know its not tables).

I have a collection of lets say "Books" (just because everyone are using it to give examples with ), now, my issue is that I want only the books titles with given author.

```
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Eq(n => n.Author, AuthorId);

            List<string> books = new List<string>();

            using (var cursor = await BooksCollection.FindAsync(filter))
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    var batch = cursor.Current;
                    foreach (Book b in batch)
                        books.Add(b.Title);
                }
            }
```

But, when I scan the entire collection result, I'm using big chunks of data, isn't it? lets assume those are not books but entire grid networks and each document is around 5-10 MB and I have thousands of them..how can I reduce the traffic here, without storing this data I need in another collection?

**Edit**
I think its called "Views" in SQL database.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can reduce the size of the returned documents via [projection](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/#projections) which you can set in the `FindOptions` parameter of `FindAsync` to only include the fields you need:

```
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Eq(n => n.Author, AuthorId);
// Just project the Title and Author properties of each Book document
var projection = Builders<Book>.Projection
    .Include(b => b.Title)
    .Include(b => b.Author)
    .Exclude("_id"); // _id is special and needs to be explicitly excluded if not needed
var options = new FindOptions<Book, BsonDocument> { Projection = projection };

List<string> books = new List<string>();

using (var cursor = await BooksCollection.FindAsync(filter, options))
{
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        var batch = cursor.Current;
        foreach (BsonDocument b in batch)
            // Get the string value of the Title field of the BsonDocument
            books.Add(b["Title"].AsString);
    }
}
```

Note that the returned documents are `BsonDocument` objects instead of `Book` objects as they only contain the projected fields.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, you can also apply an expression to the projection for transformation purposes, which works similar as the `.Select()` method of Linq:

```
var projection = Builders<Page>.Projection.Expression(x => new Page { Title = x.Title });
```

Comment: For me this solution is cleaner and works just fine.